# phonegap 2.5 ios6 iphone 4s contacts.save with photo url not saving photo

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios6

I am trying to save a contact with an image url pointing to my local image http server. it saves the contact without photo and gives this error.

```
error setting contact image: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)
```

Also it takes a while for it to go to `onSuccess` of save.

```
partial object = {
...........
............
"photos" : [ {
            "pref" : "false",
    "value":"//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/ImageServer/xxx/image.jpeg",
            "type" : "url"
        } ],
..........
..........
}

var contact = navigator.contacts.create(object);
contact.save(onSuccess, onError);
```

image address is fine , as i can see it in desktop browser